# Get posts from my own blog

Tags: api

Is there any API, through which I can get posts from my own blog on wordpress.com and put them on my other site?

1. I have a blog on wordpress.com
2. I have a single site on another hosting provider

I need to parse posts from my blog on wordpress.com and display latest of them into my other site.

Answer (score 4):

you could use the RSS feed thats associated with the wordpress blog to get yours posts, then use an RSS/XML reader on your site to display the posts.

RSS feed link example:

http://yourblog.wordpress.com/feed/

Comment: I know that. But i want to get the whole post. Is this possible?

Comment: Please try to add more information to your question then. I think you would have more control over wordpress, and be able to use the wordpress API if you were using the blog on your own hosting, I don't use the web version but I do know they use the XML-RPC interface. http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support You might want to check the wordpress site and API to see if it covers the online version.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use RSS feed. You can customize RSS feed to extent you want.
And other way is to make a connection to your wordpress blog database and then too write code to get posts.
If both sites are on same server then it will be easy , other wise you will have to make a connection to remote database.