# API's available to pull wordpress blog posts into JQuery Mobile App

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm currently creating a web-based app that will be used in conjunction with PhoneGap to distribute across various platforms.

One of the features I am currently looking at is integrating Wordpress blog posts into a slider which will be displayed in a dialog box when tapped. Unfortunately I've not found an an API or something similar that allows me to pull blog posts from Wordpress using Javascript.

I was wondering if anyone else has is doing something similar and would share what they are using.

Comment: wordpress supports rss , xml-rpc and there are some json-api plugins, it is more than you need to pull articles out of wordpress.

Comment: I think one can create such kind of api by himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

- RSS ( http://yourblog.wordpress.com/feed/ )
- XML-RPC ( http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support )
- JSON-RPC ( http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-json-rpc-api/ )

I would suggest JSON-RPC but that's me

Then I would suggest reading over the jQM docs on dynamically scripting pages

v1.2.0

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

v.1.3.0 ( Beta )

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/index.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Related Posts:

- [Get posts from my own blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743822/get-posts-from-my-own-blog-on-wordpress-com)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/how-to-get-all-posts-in-chunks-via-xml-rpc
- http://digwp.com/2010/05/wordpress-json-api-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a JSON solution!